# yeoman split angular app by modules

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular

I'd like to know if possible to separate a yeoman app by modules (like MEANJS generator) basically with the following structure:

- Module 1

  - views
  - controllers
  - services
  - css
  - config
  - module1.js
- Module 2

  - views
  - controllers
  - services
  - css
  - config
  - module1.js
- Module 3

  - etc
  - etc
  - same structure
- App.js

For me is more convenient to do it this way and the official angular generator doesn't support that structure

**is there any way to accomplish that with an existing yeoman generator?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe this generator will do the trick? 
https://www.npmjs.org/package/generator-cg-angular

It follows the Angular Best Practice Guidelines for Project Structure and allows you to create submodules with their own directories.

Comment: Another alternative is https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack which is essentially using a MEAN stack and follows the Google app structure guidelines